# What is this species of tree?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

[image]

[image]
[image]

In my city, there is a unique tree, with thorns all over it. I would like to know - what species is this?

Comment: Which city is it?

Comment: If you google the name of the place where this tree is found you might well found information.

Comment: Thank you, but this is a unique tree, there are not many trees like this in the area. Also, there is not that much information about this city's flora in google.

Comment: Can you please give us the name of the city?

Comment: Modii'n Maccabim Reut, Israel.

Comment: would be *Ceiba* sp of bombacaceae

Answer (score 4):

I am not a botanist but looking at the flower in the second picture and the thorny trunk and pods it is likely to be part of the [Ceiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiba) genus. I cannot however be sure of the exact species.

Answer (score 4):

Found it! The tree is *Ceiba insignis*, כוריזיה בקבוקית, planted in many cities in Israel. Its origin is from South America, and it grows to a height of 10-15 meters.